# Strange space between proof and the next definition

Tags: spacing, amsthm

I am experiencing strange vertical spacing between a `proof` environment and the next `definition` environment of the `amsthm` package.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\inqed}[1]{\quad\ensuremath{#1}}
\begin{proof}
    See , page 226, theorem 5.8 .\inqed{\blacksquare}\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}
text
\end{definition}
```

produces

[image]

I understand that the `\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}` command adds the space. But replacing the text `See , page 226, theorem 5.8 .` with just `text` removes the spacing. Why is that?

Comment: The question in the first place should of course be why are you doing this `\inqed` in the first place. The `amsthm` already places a tombstone, is it just because you want a black one, because there are much better ways that doing this over and over again

Comment: I want a black one for cases where the proofs are not directly provided.

Comment: Then use two different proof envs and build the change into the proof def. And it ought to be placed at the right margin, not right after the text, otherwise it will not look consistent

Comment: Sure. How do you do that?

Comment: See egregs answer, that's how I'd do it. It has the added benefit that the code structure is much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what `\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}` is meant to do other than producing

1. An overfull box
2. The standard `\qed` going to the next line

Note that redefining `\qedsymbol` to empty doesn't disable the mechanism; if you remove the redefinition, you get the following output that clearly explains the issue.

[image]

I suggest simply changing the symbol, if you really need to, by definining a `noproof` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newenvironment{noproof}
 {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\proof}
 {\endproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{noproof}
See page 226, theorem 5.8.
\end{noproof}

\begin{definition}
text
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Final note: `\phantom{\hspace{10cm}}` is just a complicated and inefficient way of saying `\hspace*{10cm}`.